# Find minimum value using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am trying to find the minimum value from a file.

```
input.txt
1
2
4
5
6
4
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
awk '{sum += $1; min = min < $1 ? min : $1} !(FNR%6){print min;sum=min = ""}' input.txt
```

But it is not working. Can anybody see the error in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use below scrip to find min value in txt file.

```
  awk 'min=="" || $1 < min {min=$1} END {print min}' input.txt
```

Comment: `FS="|"` is not needed but +1

Comment: Thank you. I am very sorry for not explaning my question properly. I was looking for the minimum value in each six rows interval. Now the problem has been solved by Akshaya in my earlier quetion..

Answer (score 3):

Set min to $1 on the first line

```
awk 'NR == 1 {min = $1} {sum += $1; min = min < $1 ? min : $1} !(FNR%6){print min;sum=min = ""}' input.txt
```

output:

```
1
```

Note that `sum` isn't used, you could simplify to this:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {min = $1;} {min = min < $1 ? min : $1} !(FNR%6){print min;}' input.txt
```

To allow any number of lines:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {min = $1;} {min = min < $1 ? min : $1} END{print min;}' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you @samgak. But this script is working only for first 6 rows. It is not working for next rows onwards. e.g. 1
2
4
5
6
4
7
6
5
4
3
2

Comment: Thank you. I am very sorry for not explaning my question properly. I was looking for the minimum value in each six rows interval. Now the problem has been solved by Akshaya in my earlier quetion..